# Is iphone simulator using internet from the mac's internet?

Tags: iphone, simulator, vpn

I'm having a question about internet connectivity in ios(iPhone/iPad) simulators. from where the simulators using internet?

I connected a VPN network in mac and i can access VPN host. But i cant access the VPN host via simulator. If the simulator uses the internet connection from the MAC machine then it also need to support for VPN which is connected.

am i right?

Comment: What VPN do you use? Is it a Mac OS built in VPN like L2TP or PPTP?

Comment: You might need to check the box "Send all traffic over VPN connection" in the advanced VPN settings in the system settings, if you're using the built-in VPN. If you're using a different program (Tunnelblick, etc.) there should be a similar setting.

Answer (score 0):

I connect with my Mac running OS X 10.6 to my work VPN via PPTP. When I run the iPhone Simulator in XCode 3.2.6 I am able to use the built in Safari to browse a web page on a work server. So yes, it works for me. Are you using something other than PPTP?